# How can I handle an async function in another another asyc function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, wordnet

I'm using a Wordnet to create dictionary entries and put them in my database. Here is the helper function that takes in a word and returns an object that will then be inserted to the database.

```js
var fs = require('fs');  // req for natural and wordnet-db
const natural = require('natural');
const wordnet = new natural.WordNet();

const generateWordEntry = word => {
   let wordObj = {};
   wordObj.definition = "";

   wordnet.lookup(word, function(entries) {
      entries.forEach((entry)=>{
         wordObj.word = word;
         wordObj.definition += entry.gloss.replace(/"/g, "'"  ).trim() + '***' ; 
      });
  });

  return wordObj;
}
```

The function above is async (I think). I want to use this helper function to generate a wordObj object and then add the entry to my database:

```
function insertWordsToDeck(words) {
   let words2List = words.split('\n').map(word=>word.trim());
   let generateEntries = words2List.map(word=>generateWordEntry(word));

   return db('words')
      .insert(generateEntries, 'id')
}
```

I know that the database call is async, but how do I incorporate the other function?

Answer (score 1):

Start from reading [this](https://javascript.info/async-await) about **Promises** and **async / await**. Then look at the documentation - https://github.com/morungos/wordnet, you can use special functions that return promises, so your code will be like:

```
const wordObj = await lookupAsync(word);
await insertWordsToDeck(wordObj);
```

Also useful:  [How to rewrite a callback function in Promise](https://dev.to/ccleary00/how-to-rewrite-a-callback-function-in-promise-form-and-asyncawait-form-in-javascript-410e)